# Storing a JSON in a data-attribute, the correct way

Tags: json, custom-data-attribute, html-escape-characters

I have a JSON:

```
person = {
  "name": "john",
  "surname": "smith",
  "mobile": 123
}
```

And I want to store it in a data-attribute.

I'm achieving this, this way:

```
$(".someElement").data("jsonperson", escape(JSON.stringify(person)));
```

And when reading that data attribute:

```
JSON.parse(unescape($(".someElement").data("jsonperson")));
```

**Is this the cleaner way? I'm talking about the escape and unescape.**

Comment: You don't need `escape` or `JSON`. jQuery will take care of serializing it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$(".someElement").data("jsonperson", person);
```

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/), the `value` parameter

> can be any Javascript type including Array or Object.